# Column might not be editable because of length

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, joomla2.5, mysql-error-1064

I am using joomla 2.5.
**i have hosted my site in shared hosting**.

Till few days I can able to save my records in K2 extra fields but when I try to save it today the page is redirected without saving the record. When I checked the phpmyadmin I noticed an alert message shown as “**Because of its length this column might not be editable**”.

I even tried to change the datatype from **text to long text** but still I can't able to save the records.

**Can anyone help me to debug this issue. Is there any modification need to be done in shared hosting or its the coding error**.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are writing to that field. If `TEXT` is not enough for the amount of data you are writing, you can change to `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT`.

For a query, the size is 2 MB limited by default. If you want to change that default value you need to edit your php.ini file and find the `upload_max_filesize` variable. Change it to something bigger that will help your job be done.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried changing the datatype as you mentioned above from text to longtext but no use.And also in my localhost i tried reducing the upload_max_filesize to 2M to replicate the error but still i can save it in my localhost.Thats y i got confused

Comment: The issue happens to me only in live site which was hosted in shared network

Comment: Contact your shared host to correct the `PHP` and `MySQL` settings for Joomla. It seems they do not fully support a Joomla installation.

Comment: sure. Can you please tell me the settings needed to be checked with shared hosting